# A change of variable to express as Lower incomplete Gamma function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

THe lower incomplete gamma function is written as 
$$\Gamma(a,x)=\int_{x}^{+\infty} t^{a-1} e^{-t}dt $$

I have found read in paper that the following integral

$$\int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-t^p}dt \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{1}{p}\Gamma(\frac{1}{p},x^p)$$

The following is my attempt to confirm the above,
I am assuming the author did a change of variable 
$$t'= t^p$$ 
$$dt' = p t^{p-1}dt$$

If I replace back I get the following 
$$p \int_{x^p}^{\infty}e^{-t'}t'^{p-1}dt'$$ which is equivalent to

$$p \ \Gamma(p,x^p)$$

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Isn't that the upper-incomplete function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake occurred in the application of the $t'$-substitution. Since $t' = t^p$, $t = t^{1/p}$ and thus $dt = \frac{1}{p}t^{\frac{1}{p} - 1}\, dt'$. So,

\begin{equation}
\int_x^\infty e^{-t^p}\, dt = \frac{1}{p}\int_{x^p}^\infty e^{-t'} (t')^{\frac{1}{p} - 1}\, dt' = \frac{1}{p}\Gamma\Bigl(\frac{1}{p}, x^p\Bigr).
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Replacing back gives on the contrary
$$\int_x^\infty e^{-t^p}dt = \int_{x^p}^\infty e^{-t'}\frac{dt'}{pt^{p-1}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{p}\int_{x^p}^\infty t^{1-p}e^{-t'}dt'=\frac{1}{p}\int_{x^p}^\infty {(t'^{1/p})}^{1-p}e^{-t'}dt = \frac{1}{p}\int_{x^p}^\infty {t'^{1/p-1}}e^{-t'}dt=\frac{1}{p}\Gamma(1/p,x^p).$$ The paper is obviously correct.